# SQL Server 2000 Page Splits per second higher han 12 million?

Tags: sql-server-2000, page-splits

I was reading about [index fill factors & performance](http://sqlmag.com/blog/what-fill-factor-index-fill-factor-and-performance-part-1), and out on a whim I tried the query given by the webpage on the company's production SQL Server 2000 server:

```
SELECT *
FROM MASTER.dbo.sysperfinfo
WHERE counter_name ='Page Splits/sec' AND
OBJECT_NAME LIKE'%Access methods%'
```

Imagine my shock when I saw the result is **12164778** (yes, that's *larger* than *12 million*).

Is it actually possible to have 12 million page splits per second? Or am I reading the numbers incorrectly? Or is there a mistake in the query?

Answer (score 2):

Please read [Calculating Counter Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371891(v=vs.85).aspx) to understand what performance counter values are and how you use them. Per second values are computed from two samples delta divided by time.

Jason Strate has a SQL Server specific discussion [here](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/11/querying-performance-counters-in-sql-server/).